# xcode pass target name to run script build phase

Tags: xcode, bash, shell, cocoapods, xcode10.1

I'm developing a cocoapod (MySDK in the screenshot below) that runs a script as part of its installation. I need to pass the name of the main executable (i.e. `SecThree`) to that script, i.e. `$FOO` below:

[image]

I thought I could use `$PRODUCT_NAME`, `$TARGET_NAME`, or `$EXECUTABLE_NAME`, but of course these are `MySDK` when run within the MySDK target.

How could I resolve the name of the main target from within a script in its dependencies?

Comment: Did you figured it out?

Comment: Were you able to get the solution?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a built-in way, but an easy work-around is to just create a variable before calling `sh myscript.sh --app-name=${FOO}`:

```sh
TARGET_NAME="MySDK"

sh myscript.sh --app-name=${FOO}
```

Now you can access $TARGET_NAME inside myscript.sh